# Error on boot after exporting VM from XenServer 6.5 in Ova format and importing on VirtualBox/VmWarePlayer

Tags: import, export, ova

After exporting .Ova file, containing .ovf and .vhd resources, I'am facing errors during
boot of the VM in VirtualBox/VmwarePlayer. Output ad follow
'''
root (hd0,0)
Filesystem type is ext2fs, partition type 0x83
kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.18-419.el5xen ro root=/dev/VolGroup00/LogVo100 console=xvc0

Error 13: Invalid or unsupported executable format
'''

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. It is related to the custom Xen kernel.
A fix can be found by installing a new kernel,  *disabling console on `/etc/inittab`* and *enabling tty.*

1. **Current kernel installed packages**

   ```
   <code># rpm -qa | grep ‘kernel’'</code>
   ```
2. **Download the latest RPM**

   In my case I had to find it because the CentOs is very old
3. **Checking the RPM signature**

   ```
   <code>#rpm -K *rpm</code>
   ```
4. **Install/Update non-kernel RPMs (optional in my case)**

   ```
   <code> rpm -Uvh mkinitrd.rpm SysVinit.rpm initscripts.rpm </code>
   ```

   (optional, for kernel developers)

   ```
   <code>#rpm -Uvh kernel-headers.rpm kernel-source.rpm</code>
   ```

   Install Kernel

   ```
   <code>#rpm -ivh kernel-2.6.18-420.el5.x86_64.rpm</code>
   ```

   > ***Note:** Use ivh option "install" because Uvh option "Update" will delete previous installed kernel, which may need in case of any unsuccessful update.
5. **Creating Initial RAM disk (optional, only if system has SCSI controllers/SCSI hard drive)**

   ```
   <code>#ls -l /boot/initrd-* </code>
   ```

   If you can find an image for the currently running kernel, you need to proceed with this command for creating new *initrd* image for the new kernel:

   ```
   <code>#mkinitrd /boot/initrd-2.2.17-14.img 2.2.17-14</code>
   ```
6. **Verify the grub configuration "/etc/grub.conf"**
   Grub will be automatically configured with the new kernel upon RPM installation

   Anyway if multiple kernels are avaible, you could specify on boot which one you want to use.

   In `grub.conf`, the value “0” to “default” indicates that it will boot from the first kernel mentioned.
7. **Edit `/etc/inittab`** , This file defines three important items for the init process:

   - The system's default run level
   - What processes to start, monitor, and restart if they terminate
   - What actions to be taken when the system enters a new run level
   - Initializes console and identifies the terminal type

   We are going to comment console line and uncomment text-only terminals as follows

   ```
   ##comment this##co:2345:respawn:/sbin/agetty xvc0 9600 vt100-nav
   1:2345:respawn:/sbin/mingetty tty1
   2:2345:respawn:/sbin/mingetty tty2
   3:2345:respawn:/sbin/mingetty tty3
   4:2345:respawn:/sbin/mingetty tty4
   5:2345:respawn:/sbin/mingetty tty5
   6:2345:respawn:/sbin/mingetty tty6
   ```
8. **Reboot the Macchine**

   In my case, after this operations I've been able to export and start the Vm on VirtualBox avoiding the previous error mentioned.